# The message filter indicated that the application is busy, while using multiple webbrowsers controls at a time

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, webbrowser-control, backgroundworker

Thanks for your time, i am creating an application which will take 5
URL's from database and then navigate each in 5 browser-controls
respectively. This activity is done in "background worker control's do
work function". On first time load of this window form, everything
goes fine, i am having a function of leave this form (which will go
back to main form). when i again navigate to this form, i am having
following exception on loading document in web-browser control.

**"The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))"**

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx

You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the BackgroundWorker events.

Answer (score 0):

I was opening each document in each web-browser-control in the backgroundworker_DoWork function, what solved my problem is by loading data from database in backgroundWorker_DoWork and loading documents in each web-browser-control in backgroundWorker_Completed function.